# Google Analytics – high time spent on page and high exit rate – how to figure out the tendency

Tags: google-analytics

One of the pages on my site has a high exit percentage, and a fairly high average amount of time spent on the page.

I'd like to find out if the people who are spending a fairly long time on the page are exiting the site from that page.

Or if some people are landing on the page, and very quickly exiting the site. While others are staying a while on the site, then clicking on to another page on the site.

Or if there's another tendency.

How do I make that assessment in Google Analytics?

Answer (score 1):

Fire up Google Tag Manager.

Create a timer event, for however long you'd like to consider 'spent a long time'.

When this timer triggers, create an Analytics event called 'xx seconds timer'. You can go a step further and tag users with a custom dimension.

Then filter by this. One way is to segment your view by users that triggered the event.